# Mikrotik post data from a print

Tags: scripting, mikrotik

If i try to get some data (simple integer) and send to external server, like below - all is ok

```
:local tArr; :set $tArr [/caps-man registration-table print count-only]; :put $tArr; /tool fetch mode=http url="http://8d11b038.eu.ngrok.io/mikrotik-api/post.php" http-method=post  http-data="payload=$tArr" keep-result=no;
```

---

But if i try to send data from a print (samples below), php dumped empty payload

```
:local tArr; :set $tArr [/caps-man registration-table print]; :put $tArr; /tool fetch mode=http url="http://8d11b038.eu.ngrok.io/mikrotik-api/post.php" http-method=post  http-data="payload=$tArr" keep-result=no;
```

Where is a problem? How to send data from a print?

And how to send only specific columns?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This happens because of the limitation of RouterOs in variable size. 
Maximum allowed size is 4096 byte. 
When you try to assign a value greater than this size - the OS assigns the value "nill".
Otherwise, if you assign a value less than 4096 byte, then the variable works correctly.

Do not allow the use of large variable.